# Как можно сделать чтобы цвета не повторялись при выводе в консоли?

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict";

    function randomDiap(n,m) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*(m-n+1))+n;
    }

    function mood(colorsCount) {
        var colors=[ '', 'красный', 'оранжевый', 'жёлтый', 'зелёный', 'голубой', 'синий', 'фиолетовый' ];

        console.log( 'цветов: ' + colorsCount );
        for (let i=1; i<=colorsCount; i++) {
            var n=randomDiap(1,7);
            var colorName=colors[n];
          
            var addedColors = [
              {
                red: 'красный',
                orange: 'оранжевый',
                yellow: 'желтый', 
                green: 'зеленый',
                blue: 'голубой',
                blue2: 'синий',
                purple: 'фиолетовый'                
              }
            ];
         
            console.log( colorName );
        }
    }

    mood(3);
```

Comment: Добавил хеш - чтобы использовать для проверки и дальше затык.

Answer (score 1):

```js
"use strict";

function randomDiap(n, m) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (m - n + 1)) + n;
}

function mood(colorsCount) {
  var colors = ['', 'красный', 'оранжевый', 'жёлтый', 'зелёный', 'голубой', 'синий', 'фиолетовый'];

  console.log('цветов: ' + colorsCount);
  for (let i = 1; i <= colorsCount; i++) {
    var n = randomDiap(1, colors.length - 1);
    var colorName = colors.splice(n, 1)[0];

    var addedColors = [{
      red: 'красный',
      orange: 'оранжевый',
      yellow: 'желтый',
      green: 'зеленый',
      blue: 'голубой',
      blue2: 'синий',
      purple: 'фиолетовый'
    }];

    console.log(colorName);
  }
}

mood(3);
```

Comment: Все так просто оказалось, правда я не доконца все понял.... почитаю про splice. 
А если для контроля повторения цветов использовать хэш, как тогда быть?